# Testing Library Unable to find an element with text

Tags: javascript, testing, svelte, sveltekit, testing-library

I'm using @testing-library to test a svelte component. In terminal tests fail when they seemingly shouldn't

```
Footer › Year in footer
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: 2022. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Ignored nodes: comments, script, style                                                                                                                                                                                    
    <body>                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
      <div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        <footer                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          class="CLASSNAMES"                                                                                                                                                                    
        >                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
          <div
            class="CLASSNAMES"
          >
            2022
             ©

            <a
              class="CLASSNAMES"
              href="HREF"
              rel="REL"
              target="TARGET"
            >
              COMPANY NAME
            </a>
          </div>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </body>
```

With the following `Footer.spec.js`

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import Footer from './Footer.svelte';

describe('Footer', () => {
    test('Year in footer', async () => {
        render(Footer);
        expect(screen.getByText(new Date().getFullYear())).toBeInTheDocument();
    }, 1000);
    test('COMPANY NAME', async () => {
        render(Footer);
        expect(screen.getByText("COMPANY NAME")).toBeInTheDocument();
    }, 1000);
});
```

The same setup seems to work in a Github repo I downloaded, so I'm not sure if this is to do with my code or to do with an incorrect config file. `./Footer.svelte` import underlines red but control clicking takes me to that component. I assume this is a VSC bug although it doesn't happen in the downloaded repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to match the `<div class="CLASSNAMES">`, you have a couple of options for matching it just with the "2022". The problem with using `screen.getByText(new Date().getFullYear())` is that it is trying to match "2022" against the entire text content of the node, which includes that copyright symbol.

**Option 1**

You could just match against the entire string:

```
screen.getByText(new Date().getFullYear() + ' ©')
```

It shouldn't need the contents of the link.

**Option 2**

You could use a [regex](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#precision):

```
screen.getByText(new RegExp(new Date().getFullYear()))
```

Normally you would use a regex literal, but since this is dynamically getting the year, this would be the equivalent (the same as `/2022/`). Also, as a side note, you could look into using fake dates in your test runner to have a predictable year in your tests.

**Option 3**

You could use the second parameter of the query to specify `exact: false`, telling it to [match against substrings](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#precision). However, in this case, you also need to convert the year to a string:

```
screen.getByText(new Date().getFullYear().toString(), { exact: false })
```

---

**Edit**: As a final note, you can use the [Testing Playground](https://testing-playground.com/) to try out different combinations or find recommendations for preferred query methods (for example, querying by role and then filtering by name, rather than looking for text contents, for things like links that have a role).